# Error: incompatible types

Tags: java, arrays, string, incompatibletypeerror

```
public void init() {
    Container cp = getContentPane();
    cp.setLayout(null);
    cp.setBounds(0, 0, 769, 556);
    cp.setBackground(Color.ORANGE); 
    // Begin componenten

    String arrayWoord[]=new String[10];
    arrayWoord[0] = letterVeld1;
    arrayWoord[1] = letterVeld2;
    arrayWoord[2] = letterVeld3;
    arrayWoord[3] = letterVeld4;
    arrayWoord[4] = letterVeld5;
    arrayWoord[5] = letterVeld6;
    arrayWoord[6] = letterVeld7;
    arrayWoord[7] = letterVeld8;
    arrayWoord[8] = letterVeld9;
    arrayWoord[9] = letterVeld10;
```

Java gives the following error multiple times:

```
Compileer C:\java\Javaeditor\Java\Project\GalgjeApplet\GalgjeApplet.java met 
Java-Compiler
GalgjeApplet.java:77:21: error: incompatible types
arrayWoord[0] = letterVeld1;    
                ^
  required: String    
  found:    JTextField
```

Comment: The error message couldn't be more clear. You can't assign a `JTextField`  to a `String`. You need to get the value of the [`JTextField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText()).

Comment: How about you read the actual error message instead of building up pressure to the community, setting deadlines for help is very generally frowned upon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JTextField` and `String` are not the same thing. You probably want to get the value from the text field like `arrayWoord[0] = letterVeld1.getText()`.

Also, you should store the `letterVeld`s in an array and just do `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) arrayWoord[i] = letterVelds[i].getText()`.